# Internet Explorer file input onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, onchange

I have these dynamically created file input HTML elements which are used with a jQuery-ajax file upload plug-in.

I would like the file upload to start after the input value has been updated. However, Internet Explorer seems to ignore the Javascript onChange.

How can I achieve this in IE?

Example:

```
var html = $('<div class="add_input">'+
        '<input type="file" name="file"/></div>').change(submit);

$('#add_inputs').prepend(html);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just replace the above with something along these lines

```
var html = $('<div class="add_input"><input type="file" name="file"/></div>');
$('#add_inputs').prepend(html);
$("div.add_input > input[name='file']").change(submit);
```

or

```
var html = $('<div class="add_input"><input id="filer" type="file" name="file"/></div>');
$('#add_inputs').prepend(html);
$("#filer").change(submit);
```

Comment: A bit more explanation: the HTML `<div>` element doesn't support the `change` event. Only the `<input>` element does. You're actually also interested in the change of the input. So you need to apply it on the `<input>` element.

Comment: oddly enough, that bit of code worked in Firefox... go figure :)

Comment: Seems that some browsers nonetheless support change event for `div`'s. Check http://jsbin.com/udake if your browser shows the alerts when clicking the buttons or not. It does for me in Opera 10.01

Comment: It's the event bubbling as bob has nicely explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you create elements from HTML in jQuery, the returned handle references the outermost element(s), so you're putting the `change` event handler on the `<div>`, not the `<input>`.

This works nonetheless in most browsers because in the [DOM Level 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents-h3) specification, the `change` event ‘bubbles’ up the document to inform its parents when it changes, so an event handler on `<div>` will get informed of any changes on any of its child `<input>`s. However IE has its own event model in which [change does not bubble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx).

An alternative:

```
($('<input type="file" name="file" />')
    .change(submit)
    .prependTo('#add_inputs')
    .wrap('<div class="add_input"></div>')
);
```